# Opening csv-file in R

Tags: r

I want to read a csv-data record into R. I downloaded the script and the data set from SoSci Survey and got the following error message:

> Error in scan(file = file, what = what, sep = sep, quote = quote, dec
> = dec, : scan() expected 'a logical', got '3'

in the script:

```
zh = read.table(
  file=zh_file, encoding="UTF-8",
  header = FALSE, sep = "\t", quote = "\"",
  dec = ".", row.names = "CASE",
  col.names = c(
    "CASE","SERIAL","REF","QUESTNNR","MODE","LANGUAGE","STARTED","ZH02","ZH03",
    "ZH19","ZH19_03","ZH04","ZH05","ZH08_01","ZH08_02","ZH08_03","ZH08_04",
    "ZH08_05","ZH08_06","ZH09_01","ZH09_02","ZH11_01","ZH11_02","ZH11_03","ZH11_04",
    "ZH13_01","ZH13_02","ZH13_03","ZH13_04","ZH13_05","ZH14","ZH14_01","ZH14_02",
    "ZH14_03","ZH14_04","ZH14_05","ZH14_06","ZH14_07","ZH14_09","ZH14_08",
    "ZH14_08a","ZH15","ZH15_01","ZH15_02","ZH15_03","ZH15_04","ZH15_05","ZH15_06",
    "ZH15_07","ZH15_08","ZH15_09","ZH15_09a","ZH16","ZH16_01","ZH16_02","ZH16_03",
    "ZH16_04","ZH16_05","ZH16_06","ZH16_07","ZH16_08","ZH16_09","TIME001","TIME002",
    "TIME003","TIME004","TIME005","TIME006","TIME007","TIME008","TIME009","TIME010",
    "TIME011","TIME012","TIME013","TIME014","TIME015","TIME016","TIME017",
    "TIME_SUM","MAILSENT","LASTDATA","FINISHED","Q_VIEWER","LASTPAGE","MAXPAGE",
    "MISSING","MISSREL","TIME_RSI","DEG_TIME"
  ),
  as.is = TRUE,
  colClasses = c(
    CASE="numeric", SERIAL="character", REF="character", QUESTNNR="character",
    MODE="character", LANGUAGE="character", STARTED="POSIXct", ZH02="numeric",
    ZH03="numeric", ZH19="numeric", ZH19_03="character", ZH04="numeric",
    ZH05="numeric", ZH08_01="numeric", ZH08_02="numeric", ZH08_03="numeric",
    ZH08_04="numeric", ZH08_05="numeric", ZH08_06="numeric", ZH09_01="numeric",
    ZH09_02="numeric", ZH11_01="numeric", ZH11_02="numeric", ZH11_03="numeric",
    ZH11_04="numeric", ZH13_01="numeric", ZH13_02="numeric", ZH13_03="numeric",
    ZH13_04="numeric", ZH13_05="numeric", ZH14="numeric", ZH14_01="logical",
    ZH14_02="logical", ZH14_03="logical", ZH14_04="logical", ZH14_05="logical",
    ZH14_06="logical", ZH14_07="logical", ZH14_09="logical", ZH14_08="logical",
    ZH14_08a="character", ZH15="numeric", ZH15_01="logical", ZH15_02="logical",
    ZH15_03="logical", ZH15_04="logical", ZH15_05="logical", ZH15_06="logical",
    ZH15_07="logical", ZH15_08="logical", ZH15_09="logical",
    ZH15_09a="character", ZH16="numeric", ZH16_01="logical", ZH16_02="logical",
    ZH16_03="logical", ZH16_04="logical", ZH16_05="logical", ZH16_06="logical",
    ZH16_07="logical", ZH16_08="logical", ZH16_09="logical", TIME001="integer",
    TIME002="integer", TIME003="integer", TIME004="integer", TIME005="integer",
    TIME006="integer", TIME007="integer", TIME008="integer", TIME009="integer",
    TIME010="integer", TIME011="integer", TIME012="integer", TIME013="integer",
    TIME014="integer", TIME015="integer", TIME016="integer", TIME017="integer",
    TIME_SUM="integer", MAILSENT="POSIXct", LASTDATA="POSIXct",
    FINISHED="logical", Q_VIEWER="logical", LASTPAGE="numeric",
    MAXPAGE="numeric", MISSING="numeric", MISSREL="numeric", TIME_RSI="numeric",
    DEG_TIME="numeric"
  ),
  skip = 1,
  check.names = TRUE, fill = TRUE,
  strip.white = FALSE, blank.lines.skip = TRUE,
  comment.char = "",
  na.strings = ""
)
```

What should I do?
Looking for help!

Comment: One of the columns that have been specified to be logical contains a 3.  Try removing the colClasses= argument.  Another thing to try is fread from data.table using no other arguments as it often guesses correctly.

Comment: OMG it did work! Thankyou very much！

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using `read.csv("filename.csv",header=T,sep=",")` instead of `read.table?`

Comment: didn't work...: ```Error in scan(file = file, what = what, sep = sep, quote = quote, dec = dec,  : scan()expected'a real', got'17"base""interview""zho"2021-04-0513:50:0222245331432433333333333TTFTFFFFF3TTTFFFFFF2TTFFFFFFF555436431811193104471022021-04-0513:51:44TF1717001.5434' ```